# How close a popup using rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a oauth app and login page is displayed inside a popup.
I need to close this popup after the login process is finished.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have named the popup window when opening it with JS in order to be able to close it with JS.

Code from W3Schools

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");   // Opens a new window
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();   // Closes the new window
}
```

In the function `closeWin`, just change the window-name to yours and then call that JS function when the login process is finished.

**Update**

According to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html#dom-window-close) you can't close a random window, just windows you have opened with JS yourself.

> The close() method on Window objects should, if all the following
>   conditions are met, close the browsing context A:
>
> - The corresponding browsing context A is script-closable.
> - The browsing
>     context of the incumbent script is familiar with the browsing context
>     A.
> - The browsing context of the incumbent script is allowed to navigate
>     the browsing context A.
>
> A browsing context is script-closable if it is
>   an auxiliary browsing context that was created by a script (as opposed
>   to by an action of the user), or if it is a browsing context whose
>   session history contains only one Document.